# Android Debug Bridge and "special" characters

Tags: android, adb

I try to write an application which allows me to use my desktop keyboard as an input device for an Android device.

My device is not rooted and from my research I found adb the best way.

But how can I inject the "longpress special" characters?
Adb says killed when I try to transfer them.

I tried AdbKeyboard from here:
https://github.com/senzhk/ADBKeyBoard

But I cant get it to work. Virtual Keyboard is on and I cant even transfer the example from the read me with the chinese characters.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

could it be that you tried ADBKeyboard on emulator? 
Because ADBKeyboard works fine on my devices but on emulator it has no function.

Otherwise I think it has to be a problem on your configuration and we need much more information.